# PHP page to re-direct URL

Tags: php, html, csrf, redirect

I'm trying to implement CSRF attack. I understood the concept of using the session-id's in one-click attack and using the brower's role in it.

I want my php page to get converted in a single hyperlink/url instead of a url which contains a code and gets redirected to the previous page.

My php code for deduction of a amount from the account is

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    session_start();
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];

    $acc = 'sn123';
    $amt = '1';

    $query = "update account set balance = balance + $amt where acc_no = '$acc'";

    mysql_query($query);

    $query = "update account set balance = balance - $amt where email = '$email'";

    mysql_query($query);
    header('Location: kclick.html');
?>
```

I want it to get converted into a URL, for eg -

```
<img src="http://bank.example.com/withdraw?account=bob&amount=1000000&for=Fred">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use GET parameters from URL try this

```
<?php
        include "config.php";
        session_start();
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];

        $acc = $_GET['account'];
        $amt = $_GET['amount'];

        $query = "update account set balance = balance + $amt where acc_no = '$acc'";

        mysql_query($query);

        $query = "update account set balance = balance - $amt where email = '$email'";

        mysql_query($query);
        header('Location: kclick.html');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are trying to implement such attack so I'll give you a basic example.

Let's say you have this script on your server (or actually something like that, can't test it now) :

**your_server.com/withdraw.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
include('db_stuff.php');
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
$for = $_GET['for'];

mysql_query('insert into tbl_withdraw("user_id", "target_user", "amount") values("'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'", "'.$for.'", "'.$amount.'")');
?>
```

Then to use CSRF, one would send a specially crafted link to a user of your application as such :

http://your_server.com/withdraw.php?amount=1000&for=Loic